# This use of posts_where() function is not clear

Tags: wordpress

I have this very short function that I do not understand at all, and the comment is laughable:

```
// This function makes the meta query work
function my_posts_where( $where ) {
    $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'bonuses_%", "meta_key LIKE 'bonuses_%", $where);
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');
```

The meta query in question is a standard WP query with `array_push($args['meta_query'],$bonusesArgs);` pushing $bonusesArgs (the meta query) into it.

Without the my_posts_where function, the meta query doesn't work. And I have no idea why (and neither did the developer apparently...!)

I am hoping that someone can explain the my_posts_where function - what is it doing, I've looked all over and can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. all it seems to be doing is rebuilding the meta query in a different, but using LIKE instead of a direct =

Like performs a search for the value in the string, instead of a direct equality.

So it would seem that this function is completely superfluous, if the original meta query just used the `compare = 'LIKE'` value.

But without seeing the entire code, it'd be really tough to tell exactly what repercussions this might have. But no matter what, there are better ways to interact with a query object than running some weird str_replace on its data.